# Iterate over multiple outputs in Terraform template file

Tags: for-loop, ansible, terraform, ansible-inventory, terraform-template-file

I am trying to create a Ansible inventory file with Terraform in the following format

```
10.10.10.10  #test-vm
```

*output.tf*:

```
output "vm_name" {
  value = toset([
    for vm_names in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm : vm_names.name
  ])
}

output "vm_ips" {
  value = toset([
    for vm_ips in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm : vm_ips.private_ip_address  ])
}
```

Terraform template file:

```
%{ for vm in vm_ips}:
%{for vm in vm_names ~}:
${mc} ${mc_name}
%{ endfor ~}
%{ endfor ~}
```

The above produces

```
10.1.0.14 #vm1
10.1.0.14 #vm2
10.1.0.7 #vm1
10.1.0.7 #vm2
```

Instead of

```
10.1.0.14 #vm1
10.1.0.7 #vm2
```

Any suggestion how to iterate over two outputs correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a list of map or tuple instead, so virtual machines names and IPs are linked.

```
output "vms" {
  value = [for vm in azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm : {
    name = vm.name, 
    ip = vm.private_ip_address 
  }]
}
```

Then in your template:

```
%{ for vm in vms ~}
${vm.ip} #${vm.name}
%{ endfor ~}
```

This would renders in the expected

```
10.1.0.14 #vm1
10.1.0.7 #vm2
```